# How to replicate or use a Wordpress News Ticker for Zurb Foundation 4 website

Tags: wordpress, zurb-foundation, news-ticker

Hello this is my first post please forgive me if I do not follow a all of the guidelines. I am building a website for a client and I really want to use a scrolling news ticker which is a Wordpress plugin. I am using the Zurb Foundation 4 framework to build my website. Is there any way to use this plugin outside of Wordpress of foundation? I already guessing the answer is no. I found this link the gives a description on how use a plugin outside of Wordpress, but it is very vague.

http://wpengineer.com/1038/embed-wordpress-functions-outside-wordpress/

The link to the ticker is here.
http://peadig.com/wordpress-plugins/latest-news-ticker-pro/

I have seen other news tickers out there using jquery and flash but none like this. Is there any tickers out there out there that are similar? Also what is the best way to replicate this news ticker if all falls. Please help thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Using a Wordpress plugin outside of Wordpress likely is technically possible, but the hassle you'd have to go through to get it to work would not be worth the effort.

I think your best bet would be to use something like [this](http://www.jquerynewsticker.com/), and then just add your own CSS to mimic the style of the Wordpress plugin you like (fixed position, full width etc.).

Here's some CSS to get you started:

```
.ticker-wrapper{
width: 100%;
bottom: 0px;
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
border-radius: 0px;
margin: 0px;
padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I am ok with designing the acual footter but how do I insert a custom rss feed like the one for wordpress?? Please help